# Excel macro to close all open workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro code like

```
 Do Until MyFileName = ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Left(MyFileName, InStr(1, MyFileName, ".xls") - 1), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbooks.CloseSaveChanges:=TRUE
    MyFileName = Dir
Loop
```

Its working fine but while converting to csv the file is opening. I want to close the file and save changes is true. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

save the new name in a variable and use `Workbook("name").close(true)`

```
Dim wbName As String

Do Until MyFileName = ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName
    wbName = Left(MyFileName, InStr(1, MyFileName, ".xls") - 1)

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=wbName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Workbooks(wbName).Close (True)
    ActiveWorkbooks.Close SaveChanges:=True
    MyFileName = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```